# NetDataContractAttribute vs DataContractAttribute?

Tags: c#, wcf

Which one should be use in wcf NetDataContractAttribute or DataContractAttribute?

the data class as follows

```
namespace ABC
{
    [Serializable]
    public class DeviceConf
    {
        public DeviceConf() {}

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ProtocolName")]
        public string ProtocolName{ get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Type")]
        public string TypeName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the widest portability, just use `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]`. One minor note: it won't use your contructor (this often surprises people), and it isn't guaranteed to produce identical xml (especially if you use attributes). If you *want* controllable xml (rather than WCF's preferred format, which offers less control) then there are ways to convince WCF to use `XmlSerializer` instead of `DataContractSerializer` - by marking the service-contract (interface) with `[XmlSerializerFormat]`.

Comment: yes marc..but i am still confuse about the usage of DataContract vs NetDataContract..one difference is regarding the constructor is there a way to findout which one is better?

Comment: Better at what? That is subjective. If it works, I would argue that DataContract is better since it is more portable, and I care about portability.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Data Contract Serializer for most purposes. You should remove the `Serializable` attribute from your class (the XML Serializer pays no attention to it in any case). Also, you should remove the various XML Attributes from your class. If you need to control the element names, then you should do that with the `[DataMember]` attribute.

Comment: it is helpfull please elaborate some more

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what type of interoperability you need. The example class has each property as a string therefore you're not dealing with anything specific to .NET. Either serializer (DataContract or NetDataContract) would work, however, the NetDataContractSerializer is to allow the transfer of .NET specific items over the wire that may not exist on the other side because the client is java.

If you know that you'll never expose your service to a .NET consumer then the NetDataContract would be fine for all purposes. If you know that you'll need interop the DataContract is your best bet.

Comment: -1: This answer is very misleading. `DataContractSerializer` works well with types other than strings, and your answer suggests that it does not.

Comment: Reworded the comment to less ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that NetDataContractSerialization serializes metadata information of the base types of the data contract classes, so you can serialize over the wire class hierarchies. In the following code, you'll be able to call GetStaff and get a typed list of staff elements:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPersonService
{
    [OperationContract]        
    [NetDataContract]
    List<Staff> GetStaff();

    [OperationContract]        
    void RegisterClinician(Clinician clinician);

    [OperationContract]        
    void Register(Secretary secretary);
}

[DataContract]
public class Staff
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Clinician:Staff
{
}

[DataContract]
public class Secretary:Staff
{
}
```

I also agree that you should better avoid NetDataContractSerializer due to interoperability reasons, unless it's a service that will always "live" in a .NET world and you really need data contract class hierarchy.

I hope it helps.